# The parenthesis confusion

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have encountered this formula in a some software I'm reverse engineering:

```
NewAmount = ((SumofRates) * (1 - (1 - BPT_TAX)))
```

and I simplified it to

```
NewAmount = SumofRates * (1 - (1 - BPT_TAX))
```

and then I took it to this (is that my mistake?):

```
NewAmount = SumofRates * (1 - 1 - BPT_TAX)
```

I mean.. what is the point of the parenthesis if you're just doing subtraction, right? So this essentially is

```
NewAmount = SumofRates * (0 - BPT_TAX)
```

so does it equal

```
NewAmount = SumofRates * (-BPT_TAX)
```

I stopped for a second - that can't be right. I tried to do this in excel `1 - (1 - BPT_TAX)` and I always came up with `BPT_Tax` as my final answer.  So the parenthesis do mean something after all!

So then why wouldn't the developer just do :

```
NewAmount = SumofRates * BPT_TAX
```

in the original formula? Am I missing something here?

Comment: A - (B + C) means A + - 1*(B+C)... you need to distribute that negative 1.  In general, A - (B + C) = A - B - C. You are subtracting both B and C from A.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`1 - (1 - BPT_TAX) = 1 - 1 + BPT_TAX`

Comment: of course!! I didn't flip the - to +

Answer (score 7):

By dropping the parentheses in the term `(1 - (1 - BPT_TAX))`, you're trying to apply the associative property.

The [associative property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associativity) doesn't work for subtraction.  For example:

$(5 - 3) - 2 \neq 5 - (3 - 2)$

When removing the parentheses, you need to change the inner subtraction to addition.

`(1 - 1 + BPT_TAX)`